# printf related Query

Tags: c, printf

Here is a simple one line program using `printf` :

```
void main()

{
printf("%d%d",printf("Cis"),printf("good"));
}
```

Output :

```
goodCis34
```

How can this output be explained ??

Comment: Ok I need to correct the question seeing the answers ..I wanted to know why `good` is printed first.

Comment: Without a proper prototype for `printf` (or any function taking a variable number of arguments) in scope it's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why `good` and `Cis` are printed first is because the parameters need to be evaluated before the top-level `printf()` can be called.

Then the return values are printed out.

**Note that C does not specify the order of evaluation of the parameters.** There are no sequence points within the statement. Therefore the order is undefined. And the result can appear in any order. (hence why they appear to be evaluated out-of-order in this case)

Comment: It's not undefined, it's merely unspecified. Big difference!

Comment: That's probably a distinction without difference. Note that I didn't say that it's *undefined behavior*. I just said that the order is undefined - meaning any order is allowed. Which is the same as saying that the order is unspecified. Feel free to edit if you don't like the current choice of words.

Answer (score 3):

Printf returns the number of characters printed. "Cis" is 3 characters, "good" is 4.

It also writes the output to the stream.

So "Cis" is printed, and returns 3, "good" is printed, and returns 4. The order of the execution of these is not guaranteed, so it is undefined as to whether you will get "Cisgood" or "goodCis".

Then the outer printf string is evaluated, and the output "34" is returned.

Comment: good is printed before Cis, not the order you have described.

Comment: you're right the answer I saw did not have the sentance describing the order of evaluation.

Comment: I think you started writing your comment before I committed the change (I realised I'd left something out).

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d%d",printf("Cis"),printf("good"));
```

At first, the arguments are evaluated.
printf("good") is evaluated first. "good" is printed and 4 (number of chars written) returned. Then, printf("Cis") is evaluated. "Cis" is printed and 3 is returned. after evaluation, the function becomes like this:
printf("%d%d", 3, 4);

So, 34 is printed.

Answer (score 0):

It's evaluating right to left, meaning **good** is printed first.  Then it evaluates the second part, **Cis**.

Finally, when doing the left-most operation, it is using the respective lengths of both of those strings to fill in the %d replacements.

Comment: The important point, however, is that the standard provides no guarantee about the order of evaluation, so the actual output is implementation defined.

Comment: @dmckee: no, not implementation defined, **unspecified** according to C99 6.5.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` and its family return the number of characters printed. In your case, it's just the length of the strings. However, the order in with the arguments are evaluated is unspecified. In your case, the second argument to the outer `printf` happens first. It could be completely different.